# Mongoid / Moped Date Type Insertion Failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, moped

The problem deals with mongoid / moped DATE type insertion.
My code is below

```
s=Moped::Session::new(["127.0.0.1"])
s.use "test"
s["a"].insert mydate: Date.strptime("10/02/2014","%m/%d/%Y")
```

raises an error

```
# => undefined method `__bson_dump__' for Thu, 02 Oct 2014:Date
```

Why does Date type fails to insert into mongoDB via moped?
I am pretty sure that mongoDB does support Date type.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB supports BSON type UTC datetime, in Moped this is mapped to Ruby Time, not Date.
However, there is a very easy solution for your code, as Mongoid provides the Date#mongoize convenience function.
Hope that this is what you want and that it helps.

date_mongoize.rb

```
require 'moped'
require 'mongoid'

s=Moped::Session::new(["127.0.0.1"])
s.use "test"
s["a"].find.remove_all
s["a"].insert mydate: Date.strptime("10/02/2014","%m/%d/%Y").mongoize
p s["a"].find.to_a
```

$ ruby date_mongoize.rb

```
[{"_id"=>"5272a943fa23bace4f7650e3", "mydate"=>2014-10-02 00:00:00 UTC}]
```

Comment: this works like a magic! I never thought that Date in mongodb is not Date in ruby, but instead a Time. Mongoize method works as expected. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help.  If you need more details for types in MongoDB, the BSON spec is a good reference - http://bsonspec.org/